# Using .net core + Angular template, how to access API once deployed to Azure?

Tags: .net, angular, azure

I started a new application using the template for Angular and .netcore, created a web app, installed swagger, and deployed it to Azure, the application isn't much different from the template as I have just started adding my HTML to it.
I am now trying to access the APIs but I get redirected to index.html, on localhost I am able to access it on a different port, the one SPAproxy starts before redirecting me, is there a way to expose this port on an Azure Web App? or even better can I expose it on the same port so I just use /swagger to access it?

Comment: What is the .Net Framework you are using ?

Comment: Please share your `Program.cs` and `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to create `.NET Core Web API` and Angular Application to run within the same Port.

Here instead of Angular + .NET Core Template, I have added the 2 projects in the new folder and running the App.

[image]

- Create a new folder.
- In `Visual Studio`,Create a `.NET CORE Web API` within the newly created folder.
- Add another project `ASP.Net CORE Web App` with in the same project.
- Open the `command prompt` with newly created `Core Web App` root folder(to create angular).
- Create an angular application by running the below command.

```cs
ng n mynewAng
```

[image]

- In `command prompt` navigate to the newly created angular root folder(mynewAng).

```cs
cd mynewAng
```

- Run `ng serve --open`  to launch the angular Application.

[image]

- In `Angular` project => `angular.json`, change the `outputPath` to `"../../Your.NetCoreAPIFolderName/wwwroot"`
- Deploy the Application to Azure App Service.
- In `Azure Portal` => Your `API Management service` => `API's` => click on your `API` under `All API's` = `Test`

[image]

***My Program.cs***

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
        await next();
    }
});
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

***OutPut***
[image]
[image]