# How to properly publish an ASP.NET core with Angular app to Azure using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, azure, visual-studio

These are the steps I used:

1. I started a new project in Visual Studio, specifically "ASP.NET Core with Angular".
2. I closely followed the instructions in this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0 (basically just runs through the process of using the built in publish feature in Visual Studio, creating a new azure web app service, setting up database, and publishing the project).

The site works locally when loading with F5.

However, the published site does not work. This is because the publish feature places the contents of the `dist` folder within `site\wwwroot\wwwroot`.

If I go into the Path Mappings configuration in Azure and change the default virtual path `/` to point to `site\wwwroot\wwwroot` the site works (though not the default registration or login authentication features).

The authentication issue may just be a db configuration issue, or it could still be an issue with pathing somehow, I'm not sure.

However, the bigger issue, is that if I make changes and publish the project again, then project is published into `site\wwwroot\wwwroot` which means that the new `wwwroot` is now `site\wwwroot\wwwroot\wwwroot`.

Thus, I cannot change the Path mapping to make my site work, without breaking any future publishing. I really don't understand why a newly created base project that I made specifically using Visual Studio would fail right out of the box. I'm new to Azure and Angular, so maybe there is something in a configuration file I'm supposed to change. I've scoured the web and tried a lot of different things to no avail. All web knowledge looks related to older versions that don't have the same configuration files.

Aside from this nested publishing issue, I'm also wanting to know why the routes may not be working for the default register page. This is what is in the browser: `mysite.azurewebsites.net/Identity/Account/Register?returnUrl=/authentication/login` and I just get a 404 not found: `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Comment: _"I really don't understand why a newly created base project that I made specifically using Visual Studio would fail right out of the box"_ - because the JS/`npm` ecosystem moves faster (and breaks faster) than MS can crank out a servicing release.

Comment: I have published many .net core apps to Azure without any issues. I am not fully understanding your issue, but just to try to help:  I would not try to change any of the default settings on Azure unless you really know what you are doing.  I have never had to change any default settings. If I were you, I would create a new test project using the Angular template and publish it without any changes.  Then you can see if that works correctly.  If so, then you can see how to modify your project to match.

Comment: Also, create a new AppService so that you are sure all the defaults are being used.  Or you can create a "Slot" in your current AppServer to publish to, making sure not to copy the settings from the Primary slot.

Comment: @GregGum I hadn't changed any settings the first time, but to be absolutely sure, I deleted all Azure resources, created a fresh project and again followed that MS tutorial to the letter. I also made the adjustments suggested in the answer by SaiVamshiKrishna, to no avail. I am experiencing the exact same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**Nested publishing issue**

- The nested publishing issue is caused by the way that Visual Studio publishes ASP.NET Core with Angular applications.
- By default, Visual Studio publishes the Angular application to the wwwroot/dist folder of the ASP.NET Core application.
- When you publish the ASP.NET Core application to Azure, Visual Studio copies the contents of the wwwroot folder to the site\wwwroot folder on the Azure web app.
- This causes the Angular application to be published to the site\wwwroot\wwwroot folder on the Azure web app.

**Fix**

- To fix the nested publishing issue, One way to do this is to use the Angular CLI to build and publish the Angular application. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Open the Visual Studio command prompt.
   Navigate to the directory of your Angular application.
   Run the following command:
   [image]

This will build the Angular application in production mode and generate the Angular application artifacts in the dist folder.

2. Open the Visual Studio project for your ASP .NET Core application.
3. In the Solution Explorer, right-click the wwwroot folder and select Exclude From Project.
4. Right-click the Angular application project and select Add > Existing Item.
5. Navigate to the dist folder and select all of the Angular application artifacts.
6. Click Add.
   This will add the Angular application artifacts to the ASP .NET Core application project.
7. Right-click the ASP .NET Core application project and select Publish.
8. This will publish the ASP .NET Core application to Azure, including the Angular application artifacts.

**Result**
[image]

[image]

**Routing Issue**
The reason why you are getting a 404 error when you try to access the registration page is because the Angular router is not configured to handle the /Identity/Account/Register route. To fix this, you need to add a route to the Angular router configuration file.

To do this, open the app-routing.module.ts file in your Angular project. Add the following route to the routes array:

```
{ path: 'Identity/Account/Register', component: RegisterComponent }
```

This will tell the Angular router to load the RegisterComponent component when the user navigates to the /Identity/Account/Register route.

Once you have added the route, you need to build and publish the Angular project. You can then navigate to the registration page in your browser and it should load correctly.

Comment: Neither of these fixes has helped, unfortunately. I restarted a fresh project and included your first fix. The artifact files were not published into the root folder. If I publish them manually, and specifically open /index.html the site works. Your second fix does not seem to be the issue because Angular is routing to this page just fine in the local site. Also, where is "RegisterComponent"? I would need to import this to add it to the path.

Comment: @LittleTreeX - Did you get a chance to look into this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74726900/19648279) which explains on publishing angular with .NET Core App.